# How to get all users in active directory via Microsoft Graph - React?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

Hey I am a beginner in React and Graph.
To explain, I have to create a little web site in React using Microsoft Graph to get Active Directory data ( like all the users and their information of the company which uses AAD ).
I am actually a little lost of how I can get this list of users. 
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Once logged into your app that have proper access right to read all users data, you should be able to retrieve users with a http get on that url

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

Don't forget to add bearer token in your HTTP headers.

Comment: Thank you to answer me ! But I just discovered that I only get the 100 first users. Do you know how can i get the others ?

Comment: You can add a $top query parameter to specify the page size of the result set. See docs here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter

Answer (score 0):

To get users in azure AD, you can call the List Users GET HTTP request.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

To get the number of users returned you can use the $top query parameter to specify the page size of the result set. See docs here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=200
```